# JSON deserializeUntyped causing exception for a JSON data string

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, bug

`JSON deserializeUntyped` is causing trouble and I could not understand why it would convert a Array of data to something that is neither an array nor a similar string?

To reproduce I am executing this in Execute Anonymous Dev Console:

```
String s = '{ "data" : [ "powerCord", "test" ] }';
system.debug('Data String :: '+s);
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(s);
system.debug('Deserialized To MAP :: '+m);
system.debug('Reading Map (data) :: '+m.get('data'));
List<String> l = (List<String>)JSON.deserialize(String.valueOf(m.get('data')), List<String>.class);
system.debug('@@ '+l);
```

**Error I get**:

> FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('(' (code
> 40)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true',
> 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]

Is there something wrong in my code here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's nothing wrong with your code. The parentheses are simply how `System.debug()` prints a `List` value. Note that `System.debug()` is *not* a JSON serialization; it's an idiosyncratic logging representation that may not align with any other representation of the underlying data. Your data is being deserialized correctly.

If you want a more standardized log output, you can serialize your data structure back to JSON and `System.debug()` that output.

Comment: I've updated my question with proper example code. The error received when I deserialize the `m.get'data')` node to it's actual data type.

Comment: @VarunC You've changed your question in a way that makes my answer not make sense, but it's fundamentally the same problem: `String.valueOf()` does not perform a JSON serialization; it yields the same representation used by `System.debug()`. If you want JSON, you have to explicitly use JSON.

Comment: Sorry. I should have Edited without removing the original question. I realize that now.
I also just tried `JSON.serialize()` instead of `String.valueOf()` and it worked. Thanks for pointing that out.